# How to find a Pythagorean triple of $2017$

Tags: number-theory

I found out that $2017$ has a square $9^2 + 44^2$ but $9,44$ and $2017$ doesn't follow the triangle inequality. So please help me out give hints on how to find a Pythagorean triple

Comment: Are you trying to write $2017$ as the sum of two squares (in which case you have succeeded)?  But in that case the hypotenuse is $\sqrt {2017}$ not $2017$.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4):

If $2017 = 44^2 + 9^2$ then that means that $(44^2-9^2, 2*44*9, 44^2 +9^2) = (1855,792,2017)$ is a pythagorean triple.

Indeed, $1855^2 + 792^2 = 3441025 + 627264 = 4068289 = 2017^2$

Answer (score 2):

You have just expressed $2017$ as a sum of two squares. $2017$ is not a square. So, $9,44$ and $\sqrt{2017}$ can't form a Pythagorean triple.

We say $a,b,c$ form a Pythagorean triple if $a,b,c $ are positive integers such that $a^2+b^2 = c^2$.

Pythagorean triples are of the form $(m^2-n^2), 2mn, (m^2+n^2)$ for integers $m,n$. Indeed note that $(m^2-n^2)^2+ (2mn)^2 = (m^2+n^2)^2$ .